# WooCommerce Payu Latam Gateway Looping - TEST MODE Works but NOT Live Mode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gateway, payu

THIS WAS SOLVED ALREADY, CHECK NOTE #2 BELOW

**Hello I am using the following.**

1. WordPress – Version 4.6.1
2. WooCommerce – Version 2.6.8
3. WooCommerce – PayU Latam Gateway – Version 1.2.3

Here are my plugin settings on this image:

http://fanninlandscaping.com/images/1pa.gif

**THE PROBLEM**

Everything in TEST MODE is working fine.

When we click pay, the gateway send us to PayU Latam.

But when we DISABLE the TEST MODE, the gateway just keep looping.

And then send this error.

> ```
> Timeout
> The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.
> Reference #1.f6e1ab42.1478806337.5e5c19f
> ```

**NOTE #1:**

This is the Gateway URL for LIVE MODE PAYMENTS.

--> gateway.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway/page-redirect.zul

This is the Gateway URL for TEST MODE PAYMENTS.

--> sandbox.gateway.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway/page-redirect.zul

**NOTE #2**

The problems were the credentials, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks there are need to check all live credentials and update test to live.

1) Change live account api
2) Change live account merchant id.
3) Change live account id.